# OpsCenter Data backup and Restore issue

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

We are restoring data backup for **Cassandra** using **OpsCenter**. We are able to store most of the tables successfully but getting failed for few ones.

Few tables having types as UDT like  ones. What could be reason?

> Example:
>
> Successful type:--item_types SET
>
> Failure:
>
> ones:--point_of_contacts SET

Please help sorting same.